# Sort according to specific specific text or date

Tags: r, boxplot

When I use `summary(mydata)`, there is a column say DEGREE containing the following texts:

```
p1
p2
p3
p4
p5
p30
```

However, as I plot relevant graph say boxplot in R, the default arrangement of DEGREE on x-axis is P1,P2,P3,P30,P4,P5. How can I move the boxplot at p30 to the last boxplot that will appear on x-axis?

Not native English speaker, sorry for my bad language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). It’s always good to at least post some sample data (and maybe give an example of what you think the output should be). Also share any code that you’ve tried so far. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Some toy data:

```
set.seed(1)
DEGREE <- sample(c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p30"),100,replace=TRUE)
```

If we now do, say, a `barplot` for how often each entry occurs in `DEGREE`, the x axis will be sorted alphabetically, as you describe (and don't want):

```
barplot(table(DEGREE))
```

[image: barplot unsorted]

Solution: turn your `DEGREE` into a `factor` and specify the order you like in the `levels` argument:

```
DEGREE.ff <- factor(DEGREE,levels=c("p1","p2","p3","p4","p30"))
barplot(table(DEGREE.ff))
```

[image: barplot sorted]

This should also work for boxplots that depend on `DEGREE.ff` etc.